# trying to get the element from JSON data through PHP but getting null error

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to integrate SMS balance to my website through  API. API provides JSON for that  . I am trying  to extract an element from JSON data. I have tried a few ways but no success . I had tried to convert the JSON data to PHP readable like this  $data = json_decode($json);.
but i am not able to extract a element I am getting error 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null' please help here is my JSON output .And i want to SMS data from that JSON through PHP
Thank You

```
{
    "balance":{
        "sms":1852
    },
    "status":"success"
}
```

here is my code this json data is store in response in below code :-

```
$apiKey = urlencode('***************');
 
    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey);
 
    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/balance/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    // Process your response here

  

    echo $response;

    $object = json_decode($response);
    echo $object[0];
```

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: ok  i have updated my question .

Comment: Please include your PHP code - make sure it's a [mre].

Comment: done now i updated with my code thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you access the data:

```
$response = '{ "balance":{ "sms":1852 }, "status":"success" }';
$object = json_decode($response);
echo $object->balance->sms;
// 1852
```